# Where did this quote come from: "What is money / tis something tis nothing"

Tags: william-shakespeare, quote-source

> What is money
> tis something tis nothing
> tis mine tis yours
> tis been a slave to thousands and  will be a slave to thousands hence
> He who takes my purse takes naught
> He filches from me my good name  deprives me of that which enrich

Answer (score 4):

It's from Othello, Act 3, scene 3.

> **Iago**: Good name in man and woman, dear my lord,
> Is the immediate jewel of their souls. 
> Who steals my purse steals trash; 'tis something, nothing; 
> 'Twas mine, 'tis his, and has been slave to thousands; 
> But he that filches from me my good name 
> Robs me of that which not enriches him, 
> And makes me poor indeed.